# Symfony2 Yaml Dumper single quote escaping

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I've got some csv translations that are transformed and written into messages.fr.yml with Symfony\Component\YamlDumper, and on strings like **d'achat** it becomes **'d''achat'**.

I've done some debugging and discovered that the string is recognized as the one that needs escaping:

```
preg_match('/[ \s \' " \: \{ \} \[ \] , & \* \# \?] | \A[ \- ? | < > = ! % @ ` ]/x', $value)
```

and then escaped with the following code:

```
return sprintf("'%s'", str_replace('\'', '\'\'', $value));
```

I already tried using function addslashes before the debugging, but this escaping is not recognized.

So I'd like to know the opinion of the Symfony community: is it a bug or is it a feature? Should I report it and fix or just check my inputs and replace single quotes (') with apostrophe (’)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In YAML, a double quote ('' - 2 singles) is how a single ' quote is escaped.

This is not a bug & the double quotes are automatically converted to single quotes by the YAML parser.

Comment: You are completely right, thanks! My problem was actually in the encoding, I needed to convert the output to utf8 before writing